# Why are there empty lines after my shape in Word?

Tags: ms-word, openxml

This question is related (follows from) this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654569/how-to-make-the-first-page-in-a-section-have-different-margins).

I am dynamically generating Word documents from data in a database. In the generation I need to have the First Page of a section have a different top margin than the other pages in the section. For reason that would take too long to explain properly, I can't just create a new section with a different top margin.

To get around my problem I thought I would create a shape (rectangle) with no border and no fill (invisible) that was the height I wanted my margin to be. I would then place it absolutely at (0,0).  I would also make it wrapTopAndBottom so that it pushed the text in the body of the page down.  This is working... except for one small problem.

[image]

As you can see there is a large, blank area immediately after my shape.  There are actual blank lines there.  You can see the lines better in this image where I've put text in those lines.

[image]

When I look at the header xml file in the Word archive, those lines don't exist. I'm not sure where they are coming from or how to get rid of them. I can manually remove them using Word but every time I regenerate the file they get put back in there.  If someone knows why this is happening and / or how to get around it, I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: Just from the screenshots its hard to tell what is going on. Can you share the code that generates these documents (please make a small reproducible sample), or add a link to the Word documents? In general, it is very helpful to create the document in Word with the desired layout / formatting and the use the Document Reflector included in the Open XML SDK to generate the C# code that will produce that document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

Sorry I couldn't post code up here. First, I'm not using C#, I'm using PHP. Second, the amount of code I'd have to post to show how the header is getting created is prohibitive on a forum like this. Third, I'm not really allowed to post the company's code up here.

In any case, the problem was simple once I saw it. We are placing multiple absolutely positioned objects (shapes, text, images, whatnot) inside the header. In the class that creates these objects each one was being placed inside a `<w:p>` element. For example, if there were 3 such objects, the XML looked like this.

```
<hdr>
   <p>Some Object</p>
   <p>Some Object</p>
   <p>Some Object</p>
</hdr>
```

The problem is that even though each of the objects inside the `<p>` are absolutely positioned, the `<p>` element itself creates a line and space for that line. So the header above would have 3 blank lines in it. This became an issue if the header had 6 or 7 objects because the blank lines would push the header's margin down and force the page's content down as well. This was undesired behavior.

The solution is simple. All the absolutely positioned objects can be placed in the same `<p>` element. This leaves only 1 blank line in the header no matter how many objects you have.